# SSIS Dynamic Connections, SQL Server names stored in a table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, ssis, database-connection, oledb

This is my first packet so please let me know if I need to put in more information. I have a database with a table on all my production server, Utility DB and WaitTable. And I have a the same Database and table on a Central destination server on the destination server I also have a table with servernames. So what I need to do is following: create a connection string from servernames in my table on destination server. Connect to all production (source) server and transfer data to my central destination. I have search alot on internet and find articles about this but there is something I have missed, because the SSIS packet works great but i won´t transfer any rows :(

I have 2 connection managers

- Connection Source - Have a expression property "connectionString with expression @[User::DemoSQLConnectionString].
- LocalHost.test - is connencted to destination server test database

Control Flow, Result of Packet and Variables
[image]

Execute task, foreach Loop and Connection managers
[image]

Comment: Have you purposely set variable `DemoSQLServer` to value `'localhost'`? What is the reason behind it? Also to check the ConnectionString at runtime, use the `Script Task` to display the variable value `DemoSQLConnectionString`

Comment: Its no reason with localhost, just a default value. The servername should come from the column servername in table servername. Could you explain more how you mean to check the connectionstring at runtime or if you have any good links. Am a real noob at SSIS. Thanks Hakan